# Why is it not required to have '()' at the end of the success function?

Tags: javascript

I got the following code:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  successFunction
);
```

I was wondering why it is not required to use the '()' at the end of the succesFunction? Isn't it required to call a function with the '()' --> somefunction() 
What's the logic behind it?

Comment: `getCurrentPosition` is a higher-order function; it takes a function as input.

Comment: In the above case you're not calling the function, you're passing it along to be called later, as a *callback*

Comment: It's the same as you were doing `getCurrentPosition(function(){ ... });`

Comment: functions control _when_ as well as _what_ and by not calling it, you allow the code to run it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function is a *thing* that can be invoked—where it runs code and returns a result. You invoke a function by using the parentheses. But, if you want to talk about the thing, if you want to pass the function around so that someone else can invoke it, you leave off the parentheses.

In this case, the `getCurrentPosition()` function is asking you to give it a function so that it can call it later on. So instead of invoking successFunction, you pass along a reference to it.

If you instead wrote:

```js
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  successFunction()
);
```

…then what would happen is `successFunction()` would be invoked—the code of the function would be run, and possibly return a value—and THEN you would invoke `getCurrentPosition()`, passing along as an argument whatever value `successFunction` returned.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're passing in the function reference, not the returned value of the function.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can pass functions as objects:

Try executing this example:

```
function myFunction() {
    console.log('hello');
}

function anotherFunction(functionParameter) {
    console.log('executing function passed as argument:');
    functionParameter();
}

anotherFunction(myFunction);
```

This code will print:

```
"executing function passed as argument:"
"hello"
```